# stream webcam with nodejs ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to generate a rtsp stream from local webcam,
I've been using nodeJs with [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) plugin, Here is my code:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var proc = ffmpeg('/dev/video1')
                //.format('h264')
                .inputOptions([
                    '-f v4l2',
                    '-framerate 25',
                    '-video_size 640x480'
                ])
                .outputOptions([
                    '-f rtsp',
                    '-rtsp_transport tcp',
                    'rtsp://localhost:7002/live.sdp'
                ])
                //.output('rtsp://localhost:7002/live.sdp')
                .on('end',function(msg){
                    console.log("finish ffmpeg command " + msg);
                })
                .on('err',function(err){
                    console.log("error found " + err);
                });
```

on the other side of localhost:7002 I've a ffplay host that work perfectly with this ffmpeg command:

**ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video1 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:7002/live.sdp**

(work perfectly means that the host service, ffplay, receive and play the stream from the camera)

Here is my ffplay command:
ffplay -rtsp_flags listen rtsp://localhost:7002/live.sdp

What is wrong with my nodeJs script?
How can I generate the exact same ffmpeg command using fluent-ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a work-around/different solution to this problem:
I've been using child-process like this:

```
child = exec("ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video1 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:7002/live.sdp",function(error,stdout,stderr){
    sys.print('STDOUT: ',stdout);
    sys.print('STDERR: ',stderr);
});
```

This should work, too bad no one figure out how to get the ffmpeg to work

Comment: I got this error `Inappropriate ioctl for device`